# What is the meaning of this stamp on the last page of my passport?

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration

Please help me to know what the exact meaning of this stamp is.

It was stamped by the Taiwan embassy when I applied for a visa.

[image]

Comment: What did the embassy say when you asked them about the stamp?

Comment: Which embassy was that?

Comment: Embessy not answered anything just return passport

Comment: Taiwan embessy it

Comment: Did you get the visa? Usually these are for visa refusals

Comment: Not get a visa its a visa refusal

Comment: Then that's the meaning

Comment: Its effect on other country visa?

Comment: It's effect on other countries' visas will depend on which other country it is.